# Unpacking windows PKZIP self extractable in linux

Tags: linux, zip, self-extracting, pkzip

I use Linux, and I want unpack a file that is daily released by an external entity in an self-extractable zip format for windows. If I would do this only once, that would be ok for me to find a Windows machine and run it there. However, this file is released daily, and I am in the process of automating the download.

Is there a way to unpack this file on linux?

If of any help, this is the header of the EXE file when run:

```
PKSFX(R)  Version 2.50  FAST!  Self Extract Utility for Windows 95/NT 4-15-1998
Copyright 1989-1998 PKWARE Inc.  All Rights Reserved. Shareware Version
PKZIP Reg. U.S. Pat. and Tm. Off.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a way while tinkering with Linux Zip.

Give the self extractable file is `a.exe`:

1. run `zip -J a.exe` to discard the preambles(stuff related to the executable itself, not the data).
2. unzip normaly to a new file, with `gunzip -d <a.exe >unpackedFile`

Comment: I think it should be possible to do it in one go with "unzip".

Comment: Aye. Under windows you just rename the executable to .zip and use winrar/winzip/$whatever_prog to extract it. Assuming your unzip binary is compatible you could just 'unzip' the file under Linux and ignore the extenstion.